# Modificar la hora o la desviación de UTC a un entorno de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Tengo en la misma maquina (y con el mismo usuario) dos entornos de Python, en uno de ellos el metodo `datetime.datetime.now()` no me devuelve la mi hora local, me devuelve una hora que corresponde con la hora UTC. En el otro, al contrario, me devuelte la hora local.

Mi pregunta es, como puedo configurar este entorno de Python para que la hora que me muestre se le aplique la desviacion o incremento para que corresponda con mi hora local (en este caso Madrid)?.

```
Python 3.5.6 (default, Nov 25 2018, 14:31:26)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, 12, 46, 1, 995228)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, 10, 46, 8, 554207)
```

datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, **12**, 46, 1, 995228)  - *Ok, las 12 corresponden con mi hora local.*

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Nov 15 2018, 20:19:03)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, 10, 47, 14, 15224)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, 10, 47, 37, 774207)
```

datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, **10**, 47, 14, 15224)  - *No, mi hora local son las 12.*

```
user@maquina:/$ date
Thu May 28 12:45:17 CEST 2020
```

El cambio quisiera aplicarlo al entorno, no a la sesión activa en ese momento, es decir, que la proxima vez que vuelva a abrir otra consola de Python o ejecute cualquier script ya estuviera aplicado.

### Añadido en respuesta a "themylogin":

```
Python 3.5.6 (default, Nov 25 2018, 14:31:26)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> time.tzname
('CET', 'CEST')
>>> time.altzone
-7200
>>> time.daylight
1
>>> time.timezone
-3600
```

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Nov 15 2018, 20:19:03)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> time.tzname
('UTC', 'UTC')
>>> time.altzone
0
>>> time.daylight
0
>>> time.timezone
0
```

Comment: Este es un comportamiento muy extraño. Puedes verificar con que variables de entorno se lanzan tu intérpretes? Me interesan valores de `os.environ['TZ']` y `time.tzname`

Comment: La key 'TZ' no existe en el diccionario os.environ en ninguno de mis dos entornos.
Y el valor de time.tzname si es distinto, en el de Python 3.5.6 es `('CET', 'CEST')` y en el de Python 3.7.1 es `('UTC', 'UTC')`

Comment: Me podrias confirmar en que sistema operativo esta corriendo estos interpretes de python

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres cambiar la hora y quede predeterminada cada vez que entres a python debes cambiar la hora en el sistema operativo, desde python para madrid es de la siguiente manera:

```
#Windows
import os
os.system("tzutil /s \"Romance Standard Time\"");

#Linux
import os
os.system("timedatectl set-timezone \"Europe/Madrid\"");
```

Las diferentes zonas horarios para tzutil (Windows) la puedes encontrar acá https://ss64.com/nt/timezones.html y en linux puedes ejecutar el comando `timedatectl list-timezones`

La anterior configuración afectaria al sistema operativo, si quieres solo el entorno de python es de la siguiente manera:

```
import os
os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/Madrid'
>>> time.tzset()
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos!